# Dictionary Api For Java (for finding meaning for the word)

Tags: java, api, dictionary

Hello everyone can anyone tell me how to access the dictionary in Java? I need API for that such that I can access all the dictionary words and meanings.

Comment: With Dictionary are you talking THE dictionary with words and definitions? Why it should exists A dictionary accesible by every programming language? Maybe can exist a library for mantaining YOUR dictionary, but only that.

Comment: This question has been copied from here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/513535/java/java/API-English-dictionary-java

Not sure why.

Comment: hey ther didnt get solution so only i posted here..

Answer (score 6):

[JWKTL](http://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/software/jwktl/) looks like a good place to start although I haven't tried it myself. It gets the words and definitions from the [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/) database.

Example usage:

```
Wiktionary wiktionary = new Wiktionary(DB_PATH, Language.GERMAN);
wiktionary.addWiktionary(DB_PATH, Language.English);
wiktionary.setWordLanguage(Language.German);
List<WiktionaryWord> wordList = wiktionary.getWords("bank");
```

Comment: hi i want to use dictionary in offline.